# how can i reload an entire class and UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiview

im trying to design a very simple game. Once the user finishes the first level, I would like to allow the player to click a "retry level" button, how do I make the UIView and all of it's data reload as if it were the first time the UIView is called?

Thanks

Comment: This depends *entirely* on how you've structured your application.  If you used a good design, it'll probably be a couple lines of code.  If not, then many many more.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to kill the existing view and create another one.

BTW: this is your architecture error, cause UIView (and any of it's subclases) is intended to display smth, it should not store any data. You have to create some back end class. Smth like MyGameController, which has to control all the gameplay and also load/reload levels or whatever.

Comment: Yea, you are right. I will re-write the code with a seperate class for the logic and another for the UI. I know how to load an UIView, but I do not know how o kill it. How do I do this?

Comment: It depends on it's retain count. If you added it to some super view and then released, then you have to call: [someView removeFromSuperView];  If you did release your view then you have to remove from super view and then release. You should better read memory management guidelines to understand all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload UIView using:

```
YourViewController *name = [[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:name animated:NO];
```

Hope it helps.